# Site permission settings will not be included in the site template

Tags: 2013, development, permissions, site-template

I have saved a sub-site as a template. Then, I created a sub-site based on the template. But it seems that the template will not include the site permissions. So can anyone provide any advice on this?

Comment: When you save a site as a template, one of the options is to retain permissions or inherit from parent. Did that not work?

Comment: @RansherSingh not sure i understand your point, when saving a subsite as a template, there is an option to include the content in the template,, but there is not any option to include permission ....

Comment: sorry I meant during site creation from template..You can specify if the site inherits its permissions Groups from the parent site (Use same permissions as parent site) or not (Use unique permissions). If you choose the former, you will inherit the permissions Groups of the site collection in the hierarchy above the site you’re about to create. If you choose the latter, you will have new Groups without users and can assign unique permissions.

Comment: I am afraid that the site templates do not contain user and groups information. All elements will be assigned default permissions, it does not matter if you choose to inherit permissions or not.

Your best bet would be to user PowerShell to export and import users. You might want to look into the following articles.

http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.ca/2013/01/export-sharepoint-group-to-excel-using.html

http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.ca/2013/01/import-users-from-excel-to-sharepoint.html

Comment: @Arsalan thanks for the reply. but i am using template mainly to allow end users to create new sub sites easily,, so i though that i can add all the necessary content inside the templete, then end users can create new sub sites based on the template. this worked well regarding the Lists, workflow, etc but the template will not contain the permission,,, so this will be a complex task to inform end users that they should stop inheriting permission and to define there own security groups or they need to import/export permissions,,,, so is there any work around for this ?? thanks

Comment: I am afraid that there is no easy solution. If development is your cup of tea then you can use a mechanism called "feature stapling", a feature is activated when a site is created and you can write custom code in the feature activated event handler. The bad news is that, to the best of my knowledge, it does not work with sites saved as templates. You would have to create a declarative template using visual studio. I will give you a helpful hint though, the stp file is just a cab file. Rename the extension to zip and you can see the contents which would help you create your site definition.

Comment: @Arsalan, even a Visual Studio declarative WSP can not do what he needs.

Comment: @Arsalan i am open to coding if it could allow me to apply the permission upon site creation.. but from where i need to start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have custom security definitions defined inside your source site, they will not be retained in the template as they cannot be expressed using the declarative language the template uses internally. Your only option really is whether or not to inherit from parent at site creation, as Ransher suggested above.

You'll need to manually recreate the security definitions after site creation, or resort to a code based approach like a WebProvisioned handler.

Comment: but when creating sub site using the template, the Parent will be referring to the site collection and not to the template, which is not what i am searching for ?? now inside the sub site which i use to create the temple from, i define its own security groups and users (different from the site collection security settings),, and i need these security groups and users to be saved in the template ...

Comment: Sorry, the template architecture does not support that. You're going to need code or a manual approach.

Comment: can you please advice what type of code i can us in this case?

Comment: A WebProvisioned event. Another thing you'll need to consider is that you cannot have multiple groups with the same name inside a site collectoin. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spwebeventreceiver.webprovisioned(v=office.14).aspx  Or perhaps a Feature Receiver https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231604.aspx

Comment: so i can force the group to have the sub site name then add -Visitors , -Contributors & -FullControll,, is this valid?

Comment: Yes, that's what I would do.