# Group Management "Custom Site template"

Tags: 2013

When I create a subsite on root and I select a custom template (generate with save as template), all the group of custom template is added to my new subsite.

If you don't understand, here is my approach.

I create a subsite at the root with the basic template with permissions "Use unique permissions"
My subsite is called "Site Template base" and groups are "Site Template Base Viewers, Site Template Base Members, Site Template Base Owners" (perfect).
I make 2-3 changes to the template.
Then I "Save Site as template" and I call the "Custom Template Site" and I activate in "Page Layout and Site Template Settings".

I create a new sub-site at the root.
I choose my Template "Custom Template Site".
I check "Use single permissions" and I create groups.
My website is called as "App site" and my groups "App site Viewers, App site Members, App site Owners".
And I go to Site Settings -> People and Groups
and unfortunately I see 6 groups "Site Template Base Viewers, Site Template Base Members, Site Template Base Owners, App site Viewers, App site Members, App site Owners".

So I return to my question how do I not see each creation of sub-site "Site Template Base Viewers, Site Template Base Members, Site Template Base Owners"?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're wondering why your new site has both the App site groups AND the Site Template groups?

If this is your question, then the answer is that the Site Template groups are baked in / part of the Custom Template. Each site that's based on this template will have the groups that are part of the template.
By checking "Use unique permissions" you only avoid that the groups from your root site are copied to your new site. You don't avoid that the groups from the template are added.

To create a template that has no groups, you could

- Create your template site with unique permissions
- Remove the newly created template site groups
- Save the site as a template

If you create a new site based on this template and choose "Unique Permissions", you'll create a new site with only its own groups.

According to MSDN and other sources, it's not possible to save custom permissions and provision these in the process of creating new sites based on the template:

[Site permission settings will not be included in the site template](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/142737/site-permission-settings-will-not-be-included-in-the-site-template)

MSDN:

> **Unsupported**: Customized permissions, running workflow instances, list item version history, workflow tasks associated with running workflows, people or group field values, taxonomy field values, publishing pages and publishing sites, My Sites, stapled features, SharePoint Add-ins, and remote event receivers.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj938033.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answers, so how I create a custom template without group baked in.

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect on that.

Answer (score 0):

I come back to you because I answer my question.

In fact I had not understood that the groups displayed in the sidebar of the page group and people are just shortcuts but are not attached to the newly created sub-site.

To remove the shortcut you must go to Site Settings -> People And Group -> Groups -> Settings -> Edit Group Quick Launch

And save the template.