# SP Online : structure of folders

Tags: sharepoint-online, folder

Can I somehow add a button that creates structure of folders? I dont want to make for every project same structure. Is there any way to make it easier?

I mean now i can add only one folder but i want button that will make
 **-** **FolderA

 - FolderB

 - FolderC**
 inside FolderC
    **- FolderD**

Comment: I guess you are not using the classic team site otherwise you could just make a template that contains those folders?
Which kind of site collection are you using?

Comment: Yes, we do use team sites. So all i need to do is creat a new "folder structure" and save it as a template? Can i also break permission inheritance in a template?

Comment: I haven't tested that, but I don't think so, as per https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/142737/178

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the template approach does not covers your needs you could just add a button in a Content Editor web part and have it call a js script that creates the folders and modifies the permissions. Keep in mind that this script will run in the context of the current user, so perhaps you should hide the web part for any non-owners

Comment: Could you please somehow help me with this? Maybe redirect me to some materials that could help me? Im kinda lost.

Comment: Create folder js: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/91b369/create-a-folder-in-sharepoint-2013-using-javascript-jsom/.   Break permissions : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh185013(v%3Doffice.14)

Comment: Thank you! As I can see those are for SP 2013. Will I be able to use is in SP Online? I dont think that theres Designer for Online.

Comment: Disregard the SharePoint designer part, just add a Content Editor web part, go to settings and add the path to the js file containing the javascript